Fetch All projects data folder data content and versions in one API call in hub browser
Right now I have to call multiple API calls to first fetch Hubs data then projects then folders and then it content I want to fetch all this data in a single API call. is there any way to achieve this in HubBrowser?
I am unable to achieve this through single call.

using Data management APIs, it's not possible in a single call.

We don't have that much flexibility in REST-based data management APIs. You can explore AEC Data Model API. Please check this bootcamp tutorial on the same.
